# Cannot access class attributes

Tags: ruby

I did:

```
class Animal
  attr_accessor :color

  def color(color)
    @color = color
    # TODO: what should this method return?
  end

tiger =  Animal.new
tiger.color("red")
tiger.color
```

I expect tot see `"red"`, but it says wrong amount of arguments given.

How do I see the value of `tiger.color`? Is it possible to see only the color, and not other attributes if color was part of an initialize method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it's right: your `color` method takes one parameter. You need to define `color` with no parameters. So

```
def color
  @color
end
```

or

```
attr_reader :color
```

the latter is the same but more concise.

One last thing: you defined setter methods and that's ok but the nomenclature is wrong (or at least, misleading). I suggest

```
def color=(color)
```

and call them like

```
obj.color = color
```

Answer (score 1):

[`attr_accessor`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-attr_accessor) sets up reader and writer methods for you. `attr_accessor :color` is equivalent to...

```
def color
  @color
end

def color=(value)
  @color = value
end
```

So there's no need for you to write any methods to get basic attribute methods.

```
class Animal
  attr_accessor :name, :color, :species, :natural_habitat
end
```

Note that the setter is `thing=` and called as `obj.thing = value` rather than `obj.thing(value)`. `obj.thing = value` is really `object.thing=(value)`.

```
tiger = Animal.new
tiger.color=(:red)
puts tiger.color    # red

tiger.color = :blue
puts tiger.color    # blue
```

Finally, if you want to pass these into `new` you'll have to write that part yourself by defining `initialize` to take the arguments and set the instance variables.

```
class Animal
  attr_accessor :name, :color, :species, :natural_habitat

  def initialize(name: , color:, species:, natural_habitat:)
    @name = name,
    @color = color,
    @species = species,
    @natural_habitat = natural_habitat
  end
end

tiger = Animal.new(
  name: "Hobbes",
  color: :orange,
  species: :tiger,
  natural_habitat: :jungle
)
puts tiger.color
```